# what's causing a stack overflow?

Tags: c, stack-overflow

I've been following along [this](http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html) article that creates an icosahedron and subdivide it into an icosphere to use for a game i'm making that i decided to try and port over to C from C#. But when i finished porting over all the code, i ran into this error `Process returned -1073741795 (0xC000001D)   execution time : 8.057 s Press any key to continue.` that i can't seem to fix after working on it for a few hours using print statements and gdb to help. Here is a relevant snippet of my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct Point3D
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} point3D;

typedef struct Triangleindices
{
    int v1;
    int v2;
    int v3;
} triangles;

typedef struct MeshGeometry3D
{
    point3D *positions;
    int *triangle_indices;
} mesh_geometry;

typedef struct IcosphereCreator
{
    mesh_geometry geometry;
    int index;
    int *cache;
} icosphere;

int add_vertex(icosphere* creator, point3D p)
{
    double length = sqrt(p.x * p.x + p.y * p.y + p.z * p.z);
    creator->geometry.positions[creator->index].x = p.x / length;
    creator->geometry.positions[creator->index].y = p.y / length;
    creator->geometry.positions[creator->index].z = p.z / length;
    return creator->index++;
}

int get_middle_point(icosphere* creator, int p1, int p2)
{
    bool first_is_smaller = p1 < p2;
    int64_t smaller_index = first_is_smaller ? p1 : p2;
    int64_t greater_index = first_is_smaller ? p2 : p1;
    int64_t key = (smaller_index << 32) + greater_index;

    if (creator->cache[key] != 0)
    {
        return creator->cache[key];
    }

    point3D point1 = creator->geometry.positions[p1];
    point3D point2 = creator->geometry.positions[p2];
    point3D middle;
    middle.x = (point1.x + point2.x) / 2.0;
    middle.y = (point1.y + point2.y) / 2.0;
    middle.z = (point1.z + point2.z) / 2.0;

    int i = add_vertex(creator, middle);
    return i;
}

mesh_geometry create_icosphere(icosphere* creator, int subdivide)
{
    int max_triangles = 20 * (1 << (2 * subdivide));
    long long unsigned int array_size = max_triangles * sizeof(triangles);

    creator->geometry = (mesh_geometry){0};
    mesh_geometry result = (mesh_geometry){0};
    creator->index = 0;

    point3D p1 = {-1, (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0, 0};
    point3D p2 = {1, (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0, 0};
    point3D p3 = {-1, -(1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0, 0};
    point3D p4 = {1, -(1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0, 0};
    point3D p5 = {0, -1, (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0};
    point3D p6 = {0, 1, (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0};
    point3D p7 = {0, -1, -(1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0};
    point3D p8 = {0, 1, -(1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0};
    point3D p9 = {(1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0, 0, -1};
    point3D p10 = {(1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0, 0, 1};
    point3D p11 = {(1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0, 0 -1};
    point3D p12 = {(1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0, 0, 1};

    add_vertex(creator, p1);
    add_vertex(creator, p2);
    add_vertex(creator, p3);
    add_vertex(creator, p4);
    add_vertex(creator, p5);
    add_vertex(creator, p6);
    add_vertex(creator, p7);
    add_vertex(creator, p8);
    add_vertex(creator, p9);
    add_vertex(creator, p10);
    add_vertex(creator, p11);
    add_vertex(creator, p12);

    triangles faces[] =
    {
        {0, 11, 5},
        {0, 5, 1},
        {0, 1, 7},
        {0, 7, 10},
        {0, 10, 11},
        {1, 5, 9},
        {5, 11, 4},
        {11, 10, 2},
        {10, 7, 6},
        {7, 1, 8},
        {3, 9, 4},
        {3, 4, 2},
        {3, 2, 6},
        {3, 6, 8},
        {3, 8, 9},
        {4, 9, 5},
        {2, 4, 11},
        {6, 2, 10},
        {8, 6, 7},
        {9, 8, 1}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < subdivide; i++)
    {
        triangles new_faces[array_size];
        int new_faces_index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            triangles tri = faces[j];
            int a = get_middle_point(creator, tri.v1, tri.v2);
            int b = get_middle_point(creator, tri.v2, tri.v3);
            int c = get_middle_point(creator, tri.v3, tri.v1);

            new_faces[new_faces_index++] = (triangles){tri.v1, a, c};
            new_faces[new_faces_index++] = (triangles){tri.v2, b, a};
            new_faces[new_faces_index++] = (triangles){tri.v3, c, b};
            new_faces[new_faces_index++] = (triangles){a, b, c};
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < new_faces_index; j++)
        {
            faces[j] = new_faces[j];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            triangles tri = faces[i];
            result.triangle_indices[i * 3] = tri.v1;
            result.triangle_indices[i * 3 + 1] = tri.v2;
            result.triangle_indices[i * 3 + 2] = tri.v3;
        }

    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    icosphere creator;
    creator.index = -1;
    int subdivision_level = 3;
    
    creator.geometry = create_icosphere(&creator, subdivision_level);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < creator.index; i++)
    {
        printf("Vertex %d: (%f, %f, %f)\n", i, creator.geometry.positions[i].x, creator.geometry.positions[i].y, creator.geometry.positions[i].z);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < creator.index; i += 3)
    {
        printf("Triangle %d: %d, %d, %d\n", i / 3, creator.geometry.triangle_indices[i], creator.geometry.triangle_indices[i + 1], creator.geometry.triangle_indices[i + 2]);
    }
    
    int count = creator.geometry.triangle_indices;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). [Edit] your question and copy-paste the error text into it.

Comment: What is the value of `subdivide`? Edit the question to provide a [mre]. `long long unsigned int array_size = max_triangles * sizeof(triangles);` looks wrong because `sizeof` gives the sizes in bytes but `array_size` is used to specify the number of elements in an array of `triangles`.

Comment: The `positions` member of `mesh_geometry` is a pointer but nothing in the code in the question assigns it a value, except where it is initialized to zero with the structure. So it has a null pointer value, and this causes a crash.

Comment: In addition to `positions`, `triangle_indices` has the same uninitialized pointer problem.  So does the `cache` pointer.  Remember, `NULL` pointers don't automatically cause `malloc` to be called when you try to store through them.  How could they?  They wouldn't know how many elements are needed.

Comment: You need to copy and paste code that has actually been compiled. There's a comma missing on the `point3D p11` line, and assigning a pointer to `int count` makes no sense. And then you proceed to do nothing with `count`.

Comment: `0xC000001D` is not a stack overflow. Look it up. Don't guess.

Answer (score 2):

You should notice the extensive use of the `new` keyword in C# in the code on the page you linked. That allocates memory for those things being created. There are no `new`'s in your code, since C doesn't have that. You need to allocate the memory using `malloc()`, from `stdlib.h`. (And later `free()` to release the resources, since C does not have a garbage collector like C#.)

`positions`, `cache`, and `triangle_indices` are pointers that you never set in your code. Those pointers need to be set to what `malloc()` would return for appropriately-sized chunks of memory to cover all of the index values you will use on those.

There is no "stack overflow" here. You are simply trying to reference memory addresses that do not exist.